# -VOUT, and COM pins for DC-DC Converter

Tags: circuit-design, dc-dc-converter, pinout

For this DC-DC converter
it shows PINs labelled as (see image):

[image: DC DC converter pins]

1.) This is from the datasheet, https://www.murata.com/-/media/webrenewal/products/power/datasheet/ust-3w.pdf   one of the few that give a schematic.
Both 6 & 8 are POSITIVE VOUT (+VOUT) it says.
There is also the two COMMON pins 5 & 7.
Maybe this manufacturer uses 'Common' instead of the NEGATIVE VOUT (-VOUT), that I typically see on other datasheets?

2.) I have 28V inputs, and this one has a 12 volt and 250 mA output (i have both 6 & 8 and also 5 & 7 are tied together on the circuit board) to a 33uF 35V capacitor. See diagram.

Some questions.

1.) Is Common, COM always the same as -VOUT with these electronics?

1a.) This is a single channel (output) isolated flyback dc-dc converter, so why TWO VINs and TWO VOUTs?  The datasheet does not mention this reason/design.

2.) IF all four +/-VINs, pins 1&2 and 3&4, (28V source), are connected, and, the +VOUTs and Commons, pins 5&7 and 6&8, go to the single CAP, is this like a serial battery style connection? And so instead of the 250mH output at 12 volts quoted in the datasheet, it is really now 500mA @ 12V...?

my diagram:

[image: circuit diagram]

thanks,

signed...
the ignorant novice

Comment: Old o - Hi, (a) As you're new here, please see the [tour] & [help] for the main site rules, as they differ from typical forums. (b) Please [edit] your question & add a link to the full manufacturer's datasheet. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a link to the manufacturer's data sheet. Almost certainly the two common pins are connected together internally. The two +Vout pins are connected together internally. Multiple pins are provided to reduce the resistance of the connection. The total output is still only 12V @ 250mA.

Answer (score 0):

For devices like these, if there are multiple terminals with the same name, it is very likely that they are connected electrically somewhere inside the device.  The multiple input and output terminals are there for convenience, so you don't have to splice or stack connectors to attach two or loads to the output, for example, or to provide a "power available" light to the input.

Connecting the output terminals together in parallel will not increase the total available power as there is still only one converter internal to the device.

The usage of COMMON, COM, -VOUT varies by manufacturers. I've seen all three used for 0 V. In the case of a negative or dual-polarity output converter, you'd obviously avoid using -VOUT for 0 V.